# Running different sets of elements through same function

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I'm trying to make a mini survey and I want the buttons to change color as I click them, and go back to clear when a different button in the same question has been selected. It currently changes the button I click to red, and leaves the rest clear, but clicking any other button, whether in that question or the next, changes all buttons back to clear. I'm a beginner so a clear explanation would be much appreciated.

```js
function changeColor(id) {
  var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')
  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; ++i) {
    var item = tabs[i];
    item.style.backgroundColor = (item.id == id) ? "red" : "";
  }
}
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background1 ">
  <div class="transbox ">
    <h3 align="center ">Q1. Disagreeing with a friend on preferences.</h3>
    <table border="1 ">
    </table>
    <table id="table1 ">
    </table>
    <table align="center ">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="button " value="Not at all likely " button id="tab1 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this.id) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Slightly likely " button id="tab2 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this.id) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Somewhat likely " button id="tab3 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this.id) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Moderately Unlikely " button id="tab4 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this.id) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Likely " button id="tab5 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this.id) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Very likely " button id="tab6 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this.id) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Extremely Likely " button id="tab7 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this.id) "></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="background2 ">
  <div class="transbox ">
    <h3 align="center ">Q2. Betting a day's income on horse racing.</h3>
    <table border="1 ">
    </table>
    <table align="center ">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="button " value="Not at all likely " button id="tab8 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this.id) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Slightly likely " button id="tab9 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this.id) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Somewhat likely " button id="tab10 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this.id) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Moderately Unlikely " button id="tab11 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this.id) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Likely " button id="tab12 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this.id) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Very likely " button id="tab13 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this.id) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Extremely Likely " button id="tab14 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this.id) "></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not add different classes to the buttons in different sections.

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean. I changed all the first question ID's to "btn1" and also changed the function to document.getElementsByClassName('btn1') and it worked for question 1. Then i copied the function and changed it to ('btn2') in accordance to question 2 and it then only worked on Question 2, clearing all buttons when I clicked Question 1 answers.

Comment: Sorry if that is unclear, let me know if their is anything I can clarify

Comment: Why aren't you just using radio buttons, which do this automatically? If you want them to look different, there are plugins that will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't loop through all elements with the `btn` class. Find the table containing the current button, and just loop through the buttons in the same table.

Also, rather than passing `this.id` to the function, just pass `this`.

```js
function changeColor(button) {
  var table = button.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  var tabs = table.querySelectorAll(".btn");
  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; ++i) {
    var item = tabs[i];
    item.style.backgroundColor = (item == button) ? "red" : "";
  }
}
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background1 ">
  <div class="transbox ">
    <h3 align="center ">Q1. Disagreeing with a friend on preferences.</h3>
    <table border="1 ">
    </table>
    <table id="table1 ">
    </table>
    <table align="center ">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="button " value="Not at all likely " button id="tab1 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Slightly likely " button id="tab2 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Somewhat likely " button id="tab3 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Moderately Unlikely " button id="tab4 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Likely " button id="tab5 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Very likely " button id="tab6 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Extremely Likely " button id="tab7 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this) "></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="background2 ">
  <div class="transbox ">
    <h3 align="center ">Q2. Betting a day's income on horse racing.</h3>
    <table border="1 ">
    </table>
    <table align="center ">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="button " value="Not at all likely " button id="tab8 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Slightly likely " button id="tab9 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Somewhat likely " button id="tab10 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Moderately Unlikely " button id="tab11 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Likely " button id="tab12 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Very likely " button id="tab13 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this) "></td>
          <td><input type="button " value="Extremely Likely " button id="tab14 " class="btn " onClick="changeColor(this) "></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to use [`closest("table")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) instead of `parentElement.parentElement.parentElement`, if you're not using IE.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Isn't that a `jQuery()` function? Or does native JS have it now?

Comment: Native DOM has it now, as part of the "living standard". There's also [`matches(selector)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) which is pretty handy too.

Comment: What are they doing, trying to put jQuery out of business? :)

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is that all buttons had the class name of "btn".

Here's a solution that adds a class names to the input based on the table they're in and binds an onclick programmatically.  Check out the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pf09qt9d/)

Here's the JavaScript I used:

```
var allbtns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for (var i = 0; i < allbtns.length; i++) {
  var btn = allbtns[i];
  btn.onclick = function() {

    if (this.classList.contains('q1Button')) {
      var q1btns = document.getElementsByClassName('q1Button')
      for (var i = 0; i < q1btns.length; ++i) {
        var item = q1btns[i];
        item.style.backgroundColor = (item.id == this.id) ? "red" : "";
      }
    }

    if (this.classList.contains('q2Button')) {
      var q2btns = document.getElementsByClassName('q2Button')
      for (var i = 0; i < q2btns.length; ++i) {
        var item = q2btns[i];
        item.style.backgroundColor = (item.id == this.id) ? "red" : "";
      }
    } 

  }
}
```

Comment: A real survey will probably have lots of questions, not just 2, you should generalize this somehow.

Comment: `class` names are not required to be unique, and making them so is counter to their purpose. If uniqueness is a requirement then an `id` is the appropriate attribute. But then, as Barmar pointed out and demonstrated in his answer, generalizing a solution is better.

Comment: Using the id on a table level is the way to go, as demonstrated in the other answer.  But if you look at the HTML I used, the way I used classes was not counter to their purpose.